# Why am I getting errors with `mod tidy` in Go?

Tags: go

I created a module with `go mod init example.com/goquote`. Then I ran `go mod tidy` and I received various requests like 'Visual Studio Code would like to access files in your Documents folder' and clicked allow.

I assumed it would just install any missing Go modules, but instead it showed this error:

```
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Accounts: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Accounts: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/AppleMediaServices: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/AppleMediaServices: operation not permitted
***
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Assistant/SiriVocabulary: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Assistant/SiriVocabulary: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Autosave Information: malformed import path "example.com/goquote/Library/Autosave Information": invalid char ' '
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Biome: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Biome: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Caches/CloudKit: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Caches/CloudKit: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Caches/com.apple.HomeKit: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Caches/com.apple.HomeKit: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Caches/com.apple.ap.adprivacyd: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Caches/com.apple.ap.adprivacyd: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Caches/com.apple.findmy.imagecache: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Caches/com.apple.findmy.imagecache: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Caches/com.apple.homed: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Caches/com.apple.homed: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Calendars: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Calendars: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Containers/com.apple.Maps/Data/Maps: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.Maps/Data/Maps: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Containers/com.apple.MobileSMS: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.MobileSMS: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Containers/com.apple.archiveutility: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.archiveutility: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Containers/com.apple.news: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.news: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Containers/com.apple.stocks: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.stocks: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Cookies: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Cookies: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/CoreFollowUp: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/CoreFollowUp: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/DoNotDisturb: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/DoNotDisturb: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/DuetExpertCenter: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/DuetExpertCenter: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes: malformed import path "example.com/goquote/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes": invalid char ' '
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.secure-control-center-preferences: malformed import path "example.com/goquote/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.secure-control-center-preferences": invalid char ' '
go: example.com/goquote/Library/HomeKit: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/HomeKit: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/IdentityServices: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/IdentityServices: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/IntelligencePlatform: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/IntelligencePlatform: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Mail: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Mail: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Messages: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Messages: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Metadata/CoreSpotlight: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Metadata/CoreSpotlight: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/PersonalizationPortrait: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/PersonalizationPortrait: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Photos/Libraries/Syndication.photoslibrary: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Photos/Libraries/Syndication.photoslibrary: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Safari: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Safari: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Sharing: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Sharing: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/StatusKit: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/StatusKit: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Suggestions: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Suggestions: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Trial: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Trial: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/Weather: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Weather: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Library/com.apple.aiml.instrumentation: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/com.apple.aiml.instrumentation: operation not permitted
go: example.com/goquote/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary: malformed import path "example.com/goquote/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary": invalid char ' '
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/fatih/camelcase@v1.0.0: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/fatih/camelcase@v1.0.0" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/haya14busa/goplay@v1.0.0: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/haya14busa/goplay@v1.0.0" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/haya14busa/goplay@v1.0.0/cmd/goplay: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/haya14busa/goplay@v1.0.0/cmd/goplay" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/haya14busa/goplay@v1.0.0/socket: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/haya14busa/goplay@v1.0.0/socket" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-isatty@v0.0.3: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/mattn/go-isatty@v0.0.3" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/skratchdot/open-golang@v0.0.0-20200116055534-eef842397966/open: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/github.com/skratchdot/open-golang@v0.0.0-20200116055534-eef842397966/open" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/cases: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/cases" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/cmd/gotext: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/cmd/gotext" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/collate: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/collate" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/collate/build: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/collate/build" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/collate/tools/colcmp: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/collate/tools/colcmp" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/currency: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/currency" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/charmap: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/charmap" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/htmlindex: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/htmlindex" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/ianaindex: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/ianaindex" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/internal: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/internal" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/internal/enctest: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/internal/enctest" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/internal/identifier: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/internal/identifier" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/japanese: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/japanese" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/korean: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/korean" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/simplifiedchinese: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/simplifiedchinese" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/traditionalchinese: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/traditionalchinese" should not have @version
go: example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/unicode: import path "example.com/goquote/go/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/text@v0.0.0-20170915032832-14c0d48ead0c/encoding/unicode" should not have @version
***
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Accounts: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/AppleMediaServices: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Application Support/AddressBook: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Application Support/CallHistoryDB: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Application Support/CallHistoryTransactions: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Application Support/FaceTime: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Application Support/FileProvider: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Application Support/Knowledge: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Application Support/com.apple.TCC: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Application Support/com.apple.avfoundation/Frecents: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Assistant/SiriVocabulary: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Autosave Information: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Biome: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Caches/CloudKit: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Caches/com.apple.HomeKit: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Caches/com.apple.ap.adprivacyd: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Caches/com.apple.findmy.imagecache: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Caches/com.apple.homed: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Calendars: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.Maps/Data/Maps: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.MobileSMS: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.archiveutility: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.news: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Containers/com.apple.stocks: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Cookies: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/CoreFollowUp: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/DoNotDisturb: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/DuetExpertCenter: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.secure-control-center-preferences: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/HomeKit: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/IdentityServices: operation not permitted
go: pattern all: open /Users/❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌❌/Library/IntelligencePlatform: operation not permitted
```

I'm not sure why it gave this error but it looks like it's trying to 'tidy' stuff outside of the directory. And I was in a separated directory when I ran this.